# Python Unit Test Mock import & check assert called with

Tags: python, unit-testing, magicmock

I have a class `ProductionClass` with a method `method_to_test` which I want to test. Class `ProductionClass` has dependency to `api`, which I want to mock in the test.

```
from my_module.apis import api
class ProductionClass:
     def method_to_test:
         data = api.method_to_mock()
         api.method_to_check_call(data)
```

The test code is as follows:
For `api` I have a mock class `MockApi` that I use by refering to it in the `@patch` decorator.

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class MockApi:
    def method_to_mock():
        return some_mock_data
    def method_to_check_call(data):
        pass

class TestClass:
    @patch('my_module.apis.api', MagicMock(return_value=MockApi()))
    def test_check_called_with(self):
         from module_of_class_production_class.ProductionClass import method_to_test
         mock_api = MockApi()
         method_to_test()
         some_data = { ... }
         mock.method_to_check_call.assert_called_with(some_data)
```

The problem is that it does not work because `mock_api` is not the same instance of `MockApi` that is provided in the `@patch` decorator. Is there a better way to test that?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I think that your patch object will get passed as first argument to `test_check_called_with` like so:

```py
@patch('my_module.apis.api', MagicMock(return_value=MockApi()))
def test_check_called_with(self, your_magic_mock):
    # Rest of code
```

You can also use the `with` construct like so:

```py
def test_check_called_with(self):
    my_api = MockApi()
    with patch('my_module.apis.api', MagicMock(return_value=my_api)) as my_mock_api:
        # Your code here
```

You can checkout the official python documentation here for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide